# Seeking Stack Exchange site for machine learning questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for machine learning questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: As neither the question nor its answers mention ML in the slightest, I'm gonna go ahead and vote no on that.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300392/where-to-submit-a-question-about-a-simple-problem-of-multi-feature-bayesian-clas#comment976244_300392

Comment: @NathanTuggy Looks like this question was once again proposed as a duplicate of that; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/62622.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) welcome any questions regarding machine learning and statistical data analysis. See our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) page for what we define as on-topic questions there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

Though not a fully-fledged site yet... There is a proposed site in area51 here:  [machine-learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning)

Comment: `Update:` The proposal was killed 15 days into the beta :(. See here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning

Comment: @Seabiscuit Darn... too bad there weren't enough users to keep it going. Oh well

Answer (score 4):

Recently started [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) accepts machine-learning questions.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with asking them on SO? It's a programming topic. I can't promise that a hoard of experts will descend and answer your questions, but you might get lucky.

Comment: Nowadays SO limits itself to "implementation questions about machine learning algorithms" (from the 'machine-learning' tag wiki). Questions about machine learning per se are migrated to Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1):

As bmargulies suggests, this topic doesn't strike me as out of place for StackOverflow.

For a more ML-specific site, you could try asking on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ -- or check the [list of stackexchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites).