# Where to submit a question about a simple problem of multi-feature Bayesian classification

Tags: support, site-recommendation, statistics

The problem comes from §3.1.2 in the "Temporal Data Mining" book by Theophano Mitsa 
I'm looking for help to calculate the value of the marginal distribution and the exact posterior distribution (the book does not give these values since they are not needed for classification)

Where would you submit this?

*this is not really a computer science question*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), the SE site for Q&A for **statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization**. There you can ask those sorts of questions, as Bayesian methods are part of ML.

Comment: posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/300887/175696